# Why does Dafny think there might be a problem with this precondition when using a ghost variable?

Tags: dafny

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class Testing {
    ghost var myGhostVar: int;

    method Init() 
    modifies this
    ensures this.myGhostVar == -1    
    {
        this.myGhostVar := -1;
        assert this.myGhostVar == -1;
    }


    method MyTestingMethod(list: array<int>, t: int)
    modifies this
    requires list.Length > 1
    requires this.myGhostVar == -1
    requires t == -1
    ensures MyPredicate(list, myGhostVar)
    ensures this.myGhostVar < list.Length
    {
        this.Init();
        assert this.myGhostVar < 0;
        assert list.Length > 0;
        assert this.myGhostVar < list.Length;
    }

    predicate MyPredicate(list: array<int>, startIndex: int)
    requires startIndex < list.Length
    {
        true
    }
}
```

For some reason, Dafny say that the call to `MyPredicate(...)` might not hold. But if I instead use `t` as the argument instead of `myGhostVar`; Dafny has no complaints.

Both have the same `requires` predicate which makes it all a bit confusing. Is it something that I am missing when using ghost variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an issue with ghost variables - you could check and see that you'd have the same issue if you removed the `ghost` keyword.

The issue is that to call `MyPredicate(list, myGhostVar)`, you need to satisfy the pre-condition, which here would be `myGhostVar < list.Length`.

You actually have this condition in your ensures clause, which is great!

```
    ensures MyPredicate(list, myGhostVar)
    ensures this.myGhostVar < list.Length
```

But your call to `MyPredicate` is *before* the condition you need. Try flipping around the order:

```
    ensures this.myGhostVar < list.Length
    ensures MyPredicate(list, myGhostVar)
```

And you should see that Dafny stops complaining.

In general, Dafny will try to prove that the pre-conditions within an `ensures` clauses hold using the *previous* ensures clauses.

> Both have the same requires predicate which makes it all a bit confusing. Is it something that I am missing when using ghost variables?

Here, I think you're asking about the clauses

```
    requires this.myGhostVar == -1
    requires t == -1
```

and wondering why it can't use the `this.myGhostVar == -1` pre-condition to prove `this.myGhostVar < list.Length`.

The answer is that the `this.myGhostVar == -1` is a pre-condition, meaning Dafny knows that it holds on entry, but the value of `this.myGhostVar` might change during the execution of the method. So that doesn't help Dafny when checking the post-condition.

Note that Dafny doesn't look at the body of its methods when checking the well-formedness of its post-conditions. For that purpose, Dafny only knows what you tell it in the method signature.